# Weird Javascript behaviour when working with date

Tags: javascript, html

Basically i try to take the value of data attributes when clicked the values are 7,14,30 and i try insert them into some javascript date code but it dont show the correct date? if i put in the values myself it will alert the correct dates but when i use a javascript variable which holds one of the data attributes i will get dates far away from the real date?

Sample site [here](http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/VIGTIG/LOGINS/login/index.php?page=opretAuction)

HTML

```
<form class="annonceForm" action="index.php?page=opretAuction" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Produkt">

    <div id="auctionExpireWrapper" class="auctionExpireWrapper">
        <span data-auctionExpire="7" class="auctionExpire">7 dage</span>
        <span data-auctionExpire="14" class="auctionExpire">14 dage</span>
        <span data-auctionExpire="30" class="auctionExpire">30 dage</span>
    </div>
    <input id="auctionStartDateInput" type="hidden">
    <input id="auctionEndDateInput" type="hidden">

    <textarea placeholder="Beskrivelse"></textarea>
           <!-- HIDDEN INPUT FELTER -->
           <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['CSRFToken']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="OpretAuctionAuctioneer" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"> 
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("auctionExpireWrapper").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
var expireDate = e.target.getAttribute("data-auctionExpire");
alert(expireDate);
var today = new Date();
```

When i use the expireDate variable it mess up the date, if i insert etc 14 manually without the variable everything works fine?

```
today.setDate(today.getDate() + expireDate);
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
alert(today);
});
```

Could anyone explain to me why it behaves like this?

Comment: the data attribute `data-auctionExpire` is not really valid. You have to use `e.target.dataset.auctionexpire` to get the data-attribute value. Please note the 'E' as lower case.

Comment: What is the difference between dataset.auctionExpire? and why is the e lower case?

And thanks alot

Comment: It still seem to be showing the wrong date? and for some reason when the "7" is pressed it show the correct date but when 14 or 30 is pressed it shows a wrong date?

Comment: submitted an answer instead of comment due of longevity of it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer instead of further comments. OP has asked the following question in the comments:

> What is the difference between dataset.auctionExpire? and why is the e lower case?

Because it's defined by this way. If you check the [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) documentation, you will find

> The name of a custom data attribute in HTML begins with data-. It must contain only letters, numbers and the following characters: dash (-), dot (.), colon (:), underscore (_) -- **but NOT any ASCII capital letters (A to Z)**.

However, in your HTML, you can define your `data-` attribute with uppercase like you did here:

```
<span data-auctionExpire="7"
```

But internally, it will be stored as `auctionexpire`. Each similar named attribute that follows doesn't get added. Here below is a small example where I have added multiple data-attributes. The only difference is that some characters are in uppercase:

```js
document.getElementById('forTest').addEventListener('click', function() {
   console.log('this.dataset.auctionexp: ' +  this.dataset.auctionexp);
   console.log('this.dataset.auctionExp: ' +  this.dataset.auctionExp);
   console.log('this.dataset.auCTionexp: ' +  this.dataset.auCTionexp);
   console.log('this.dataset.AUCTIONEXP: ' +  this.dataset.AUCTIONEXP);
});
```

```html
<span id="forTest" data-auctionExp="one uppercase" data-auCTionexp="CT as upper" data-AUCTIONEXP="FULL UPPER">clickme</span>
```

In order to fix your problem, I have replaced the second line. But that's not the only problem. The type of the value that you retrieve from `.dataset.auctionexpire` is of type `string`. When you're doing

```
today.setDate(today.getDate() + expireDate)
```

you're adding an integer with a string value

```
  today.getDate() // = 13, type Number (time of this post)
  expireDate      // =  7, type String(clicked on "7 tage")
+ ----------------------
  // result: 137
```

So you were setting the new day part with 137 days instead of 20 (`13+7`). To fix it, simply cast the string to number by using `new Number()` like I did here below.

```js
document.getElementById("auctionExpireWrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var expireDate = e.target.dataset.auctionexpire;
  // expireDate is a string, not number. You have to cast it
  expireDate = new Number(expireDate);
  // should be correct now.
  
  console.log('expireDate: ' + expireDate);
  
  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate() + expireDate);
  
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  console.log('today: ' + today);
});
```

```html
<form class="annonceForm" action="index.php?page=opretAuction" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Produkt">

  <div id="auctionExpireWrapper" class="auctionExpireWrapper">
    <span data-auctionExpire="7" class="auctionExpire">7 dage</span>
    <span data-auctionExpire="14" class="auctionExpire">14 dage</span>
    <span data-auctionExpire="30" class="auctionExpire">30 dage</span>
  </div>
  <input id="auctionStartDateInput" type="hidden">
  <input id="auctionEndDateInput" type="hidden">

  <textarea placeholder="Beskrivelse"></textarea>
  <!-- HIDDEN INPUT FELTER -->
  <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['CSRFToken']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="OpretAuctionAuctioneer" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Thats an amazing answer, and thanks for taking the time to do an in dept answer i cant believe i did not think about it being a string or atleast check for it i would for sure have checkked if it was PHP, i just assume Javascript converts numbers to numbers if Javascript thinks that it is a number (I think i read that this is what Javascript do somewhere).

Anyway thanks alot great answer